# BytesMessage without OOM

Tags: java, jms, out-of-memory

Is there a way to put a large file in a JMS queue without loading the whole thing in memory? Let's say the file is 100MB, can I stream it in and out of a queue or must I load the whole byte array in memory?

Comment: I would make sure you have more memory or break up your messages into manageable sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not directly supported by JMS. But there are JMS-supporting implementations, such as Apache ActiveMQ that support passing streams. See [this page](http://activemq.apache.org/jms-streams.html) on the ActiveMQ site for more information.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use Apache Camel in combination with your Message Broker.

Making use of the Enterprise Integration Pattern [here](http://camel.apache.org/claim-check.html) you can deposit your file in a central store. Then the message (headers and reference to claim) is sent like a normal message through your Broker. Then when delivering the message the file can be picked up again.

For example:

```
<route>
<from uri="direct:start"/>
<pipeline>
    <to uri="bean:checkLuggage"/>
    <to uri="mock:testCheckpoint"/>
    <to uri="bean:dataEnricher"/>
    <to uri="mock:result"/>
</pipeline>
</route>
```

Where `checkLuggage` looks like this:

```
public static final class CheckLuggageBean {        
  public void checkLuggage(Exchange exchange, @Body String body, @XPath("/order/@custId") String custId) {   
    // store the message body into the data store, using the custId as the claim check
    dataStore.put(custId, body);
    // add the claim check as a header
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("claimCheck", custId);
    // remove the body from the message
    exchange.getIn().setBody(null);
}
```

}

And `dataEnricher` looks like this:

```
public static final class DataEnricherBean {
  public void addDataBackIn(Exchange exchange, @Header("claimCheck") String claimCheck) { 
    // query the data store using the claim check as the key and add the data
    // back into the message body
    exchange.getIn().setBody(dataStore.get(claimCheck));
    // remove the message data from the data store
    dataStore.remove(claimCheck);
    // remove the claim check header
    exchange.getIn().removeHeader("claimCheck");
  }
}
```